# AIC to determine optimal degrees of freedom for natural spline in GLMM?

Tags: aic, glmm, splines, degrees-of-freedom

Is it appropriate to use AIC to determine the optimal degrees of freedom for a natural spline?

I have measured 200 animals at six points in time. My data look like below.

```
plot(long$t_days, long$lweight_t)
```

[image: Animal weight through time]

To capture the non-linear relationship between animal weight and time I am using a natural spline implemented through the `ns()` function in the `splines` package.

I first built the below model, in which my spline has two degrees of freedom. This model has an AICc value of 519.

```
w8 <- glmmTMB(lweight_t ~ 
+                   tagged + ns(t_days, df = 2) + (t_days | scale_id), 
+                 data = long, family = gaussian) 

AICcmodavg::AICc(w8)
[1] 519.0959
```

When I check the residuals of this model using the `DHARMa` package it appears that my model does not adequately capture variability in animal weight through time.

```
sim_resid_w8 <- simulateResiduals(fittedModel = w8, n = 250)
plot(sim_resid_w8)
plotResiduals(sim_resid_w8, 
+               form = long$t_days[!is.na(long$lweight_t)])
```

[image: DHARMa plot 1]
[image: DHARMa plot 2]

If I increase the number of degrees of freedom in my spline my models AICc values and residuals improve substantially. A spline with 5 degrees of freedom gives me the best AICc score - 276. Beyond 5 degrees of freedom my models AICc score and residuals improve little.

```
w8 <- glmmTMB(lweight_t ~ 
+                   tagged + ns(t_days, df = 5) + (t_days | scale_id), 
+                 data = long, family = gaussian) 
AICcmodavg::AICc(w8)
[1] 276.1959

sim_resid_w8 <- simulateResiduals(fittedModel = w8, n = 250)
plot(sim_resid_w8)
plotResiduals(sim_resid_w8, 
+               form = long$t_days[!is.na(long$lweight_t)])
```

[image: DHARMa plot 3]
[image: DHARMa plot 4]

Is it appropriate to use AIC in this way to determine the optimal degrees of freedom for a natural spline?

This is the first time I have used splines in GLMMs, but I am aware that overfitting is a problem when using splines and acknowledge that I only have six data points for each of the 200 animals in my dataset. I was unsure if it would be appropriate to have a spline with five degrees of freedom with so few points per individual.

Thanks

Edit: I see [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/307163/how-many-knots-for-restricted-cubic-splines) suggests that using AIC to select optimal knots/degrees of freedom for splines might be ok

Comment: Pat, is your animal weight log-transformed prior to being included in the model? If yes, that would complicate interpretation.  Anyway, from your plot of the data, it looks like the 6 occasions when the animals were measured were pre-specified - is that correct? If yes, why not code Time as a factor in your model, with levels corresponding to the 6 occasions? Then your model can include tagged + Time in its fixed effects person and Time in its random effects portion. You might even be able to include tagged*Time in your model.

Comment: Thanks Isabella. The 6 occasions when the animals were measured were approximately 2-3 months apart, it was intended that they were approximately evenly spaced time points. I had previously coded time as a factor, but was told by a reviewer that they wanted time as a numeric and something to account for the non-linear relationship between time and weight.....

Comment: Yes my data have been log transformed to improve homoscedasticity. Variance was originally very uneven across the 6 time points, very little variance at time point 1 and lots of variance at time point 6, variance increased through time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pat, I still see some evidence of heteroscedasticity even after log-transforming the data.

If your interest is in describing the overall shape of the temporal trend in log weight for a typical animal in your study, why not use the bam() function in the mgcv package of R? Then you can consider three different models:

```
# Model 1: random intercepts model
m1 <- bam(lweight_t ~ tagged + 
                      s(t_days) + 
                      s(scale_id, bs = "re"), 
          data = long)

# Model 2: random intercepts and slopes model 
m2 <- bam(lweight_t ~ tagged + 
                      s(t_days) + 
                      s(scale_id, bs = "re") + 
                      s(scale_id, t_days, bs="re"), 
          data = long)

# Model 3: random smooths model 
m3 <- bam(lweight ~ tagged + 
                    s(t_days) + 
                    s(t_days, scale_id, bs="fs", m=1), 
          data = long)
```

The paper *GENERALISED ADDITIVE MIXED MODELS FOR DYNAMIC ANALYSIS IN LINGUISTICS: A PRACTICAL INTRODUCTION* by Márton Sóskuthy (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.05339.pdf) does a nice job at explaining the difference between these 3 models.

Notice that you do not have to specify the degree of smoothness of the smooth s(t_days) in your model - it will automatically be estimated.

You can compare the 3 models in terms of their AIC values (as well as adjusted R-squared values and deviance explained) to see which one seems most appropriate for your data.

The link http://jacolienvanrij.com/Tutorials/GAMM.html explains how you can visualize the results produced by each model using the **itsadug** package in R.

The suggested models are referred to as *hierarchical generalized additive models* and have also been explored in the paper **Hierarchical generalized additive models
in ecology: an introduction with mgcv** by Eric Pedersen et al., which is available here:
https://peerj.com/articles/6876.pdf.